# Terraform azuread_application seems to be missing arguments

Tags: azure-active-directory, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am automating my Azure Active Directory application.
If I look at the manifest in Azure I can see a lot more items than are available in the Terraform => azuread_application.

For example, I want to set the `oauth2Permissions`:
[image]

Or I want to set the `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` to 2 here:
[image]

But Terraform only seems to export these items:
[image]

So, the reason for this question is, what is best practice for creating an Azure AD Application Via Terraform?

- Is the `azuread_application` one of those resource (like a `azurerm_function_app`) where some things are just not available to do via Terraform
- Or am I expected to use Terraform in combination with a script like PowerShell?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

some of the things are not possible with terraform, nothing you can really do about that except implementing it yourself and submitting a PR. You can use terraform in combination with powershell\az cli script to perform configurations that are not possible with it yet.