# Terraform : How do I set the value of accessTokenAcceptedVersion to 2 for a Azure Service Principal?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-service-principal

I have used the below terraform script to provision the service principal in Azure

```
resource "azuread_application" "app" {
  display_name = "app"
  owners       = "xxxx"
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "principal" {
  application_id = azuread_application.app.application_id
}
```

I could see the manifest mentioned below

[image]

However, I want to set the value of **accessTokenAcceptedVersion to 2** using the terraform.

How do I set the value of accessTokenAcceptedVersion to 2 for a Azure Service Principal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I want to set the value of**accessTokenAcceptedVersion to 2** using the terraform.

Unfortunately, **Terraform** does not support changing the value of`access_token_issued_version` in the   `Application registration`. Follow the document to check the [arguments are supported](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/1.6.0/docs/resources/application_oauth2_permission_scope#admin_consent_display_name) in Terraform.

Alternatively, you can use `Microsoft Graph` commands to change the `access_token_issued_version` to 2.

```
Connect-MgGraph -TenantId "TenantID" -Scopes "Application.readwrite.all"
    Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Applications
    $AppId="Azure AD Application ID"
    $paramets = @{
        Api = @{
            RequestedAccessTokenVersion = 2
        }
    }
    Update-MgApplication -ApplicationId $AppId -BodyParameter $paramets
```

Once the above code is run ,`AccessTokenVersion` has been updated successfully.

[image]

Reference: [Terraform azuread_application seems to be missing arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57047623/terraform-azuread-application-seems-to-be-missing-arguments) by `4c74356b41`

Comment: Thank you. I will try something like $uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/<app objectId>"
az rest --method PATCH --uri '$uri' --headers 'Content-Type=application/json' --body '{\""api\"":{\""requestedAccessTokenVersion\"":2}}'

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change the value of manifest's **accessTokenAcceptedVersion** like this:

```
resource "azuread_application" "app" {
  display_name = "app"
  owners       = "xxxx"

  api {
    requested_access_token_version = 2
  }
}
```